# Parse error Unexpected T_IF

Tags: php, sql

What i want to do is when `semester` is equals to "1" it will print **"st Semester S.Y"** else if `semester` is equals to "2" it will print **"nd Semester S.Y"**. But the problem is i get an error of `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)`. Can someone help me about this?

here's my code.

```
if(isset($_POST['loadsem'])){
      $stud = $_POST['stud'];
        $output = '';  
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT sch_year,semester FROM grades WHERE stud_no ='$stud'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $output .= '
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                      <tr>
                    <th>Semesters Attended</th>
                      </tr>';
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $sem = $row['semester'];
        $year = $row['sch_year'];
        $output .= '<tr>
                    <td><a href="">'.
                     if($sem == "1"){
                      $row['semester']. "st Semester S.Y" .$row['sch_year']
                    }
                    else{
                      $row['semester']. "nd Semester S.Y" .$row['sch_year']
                    }
                    .'</a></td>
                    </tr>
          ';
      }
          $output .= '</table>
            </div>';
   echo $output;


}
```

Comment: You cannot concatenate conditional operator into a string. instead break your variable

Comment: You can't do a `if`/`else` block in the middle of a variable concatenate -  `$output .= '<tr>...'.  if(){ } else{ } .'... ';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot concatenate an `if` statement.

```
$output .= '<tr>
    <td><a href="">';
if($sem == "1") {
  $output .= $row['semester']. "st Semester S.Y" .$row['sch_year'];
} else {
  $output .= $row['semester']. "nd Semester S.Y" .$row['sch_year'];
}
$output .='</a></td>
    </tr>';
```

If you still wanna concatenate, you need to use ternary operator: `(condition) ? true : false`.

Comment: Unexpecter { sir.

Comment: You forgot the `;` maybe? hehe. Thankyou :)

Comment: @nethken Thanks. Approved your change boss. `:D`

Comment: Thankyou sir. Im just a beginner. Can you recommend some site to read and know some rules to php and html?

Comment: @nethken Go for php.net. Or I personally chose PHP 5 for Dummies, but now it is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

You cant do a function in if statesments so allways when u canna do php code end your print or varable. and add the new code

exemple 1:

```
echo 'hello'; 
if($world == true){
 echo 'foo';
}else{
 echo 'bar;'
}
```

exemple 2:

```
$i = 'hello'; 
if($world == true){
$i .='foo';
}else{
$i .='bar;'
}
```

in both exemple i end.

.= means add so you know

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use if else like that, but you can use ?: in (). Here is a simple [demo](https://eval.in/701114)

change you if else

```
if($sem == "1"){
  $row['semester']. "st Semester S.Y" .$row['sch_year']
}
else{
  $row['semester']. "nd Semester S.Y" .$row['sch_year']
}
```

to: (?:)

```
($sem == "1" ? $row['semester']. "st Semester S.Y" .$row['sch_year'] : $row['semester']. "nd Semester S.Y" .$row['sch_year'])
```